# "Не знаю, как сделать анимацию" - как объяснить запятую в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

> Не знаю, как сделать анимацию.

Нужна ли тут запятая? Как ее объяснить?

Comment: Нужна - это сложноподчиненное предложение.

Answer (score 1):

Это  сложноподчиненное предложение.

> Придаточные предложения отделяются от главного запятыми.
>
> Средствами связи придаточного и главного предложений являются:
>   •в придаточном предложении – подчинительные союзы (что, чтобы, ибо, пока, когда, **как**, если и др.) или союзные слова (который, какой, кто, что, **как**, где, куда, откуда, когда и др.);
>
> Я знаю, как она любит сына (как – союзное слово).

Подробнее здесь: [2.1. Общая характеристика сложноподчинённых предложений](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html)

Comment: Я знаю, как она любит сына. Вроде бы "как" - союз? Он заменяет союз "что": Было слышно, как дождь стучит по крыше. Или нет?

Comment: @Ксения, Нет, по-моему. "Как сильно она любит сына", но "...что дождь стучит по крыше". Ну и вообще ЛИЦЕЙ - авторитетный сайт.

Comment: Может быть, может быть... А в таком предложении: Я вижу, как белка прыгает по веткам. Союз "как" имеет значение чувственного восприятия, в отличие от нейтрального союза "что".  Здесь нет значения "каким образом", которое обычно имеет местоимение "как". Кстати, это значение (каким образом) присутствует в приведенном в вопросе предложении.